# Div change color on click only on outer edges?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code written that when the div is selected it changes to a blueish color. I ran into a bug that when you click in the middle of the div, this function doesnt run. So only when you click on the outer edges this works. I think it has something to do with parentNode or something similar to this. Been trying to figure this out. Any tips please? I will be learning domevents.dev after this project!

```js
let headers = document.getElementsByClassName("options__container--option");

function getSectionId(header) {
  return header.parentNode.parentNode.id;
}

for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  headers[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let isNotActive = !this.classList.contains("active");
    let sectionsId = getSectionId(this);

    console.log(`sectionsId: ${sectionsId}`);

    for (const header of headers) {
      if (getSectionId(header) == sectionsId) {
        header.classList.remove("active");
      }
    }

    if (isNotActive) {
      this.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.options__container--option.active {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<main class="subscription__container">
  <section
    id="preferences"
    class="subscription__container--preferences box"
  >
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">
        How do you drink your coffee?
      </h3>
      <img
        class="question__container--img"
        src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
        alt="arrow"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="capsule">
          <input
            id="capsule"
            type="radio"
            data-preference="Capsule"
            value="Capsule"
            name="preferences"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Capsule</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Compatible with Nespresso systems and similar brewers.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="filter">
          <input
            id="filter"
            type="radio"
            data-preference="Filter"
            value="Filter"
            name="preferences"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and 
            V60.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="espresso">
          <input
            id="espresso"
            type="radio"
            data-preference="Espresso"
            value="Espresso"
            name="preferences"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Espresso</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavorful
            experience.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="bean" class="subscription__container--beans box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">What type of coffee?</h3>
      <img
        class="question__container--img"
        src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
        alt="arrow"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="single">
          <input
            id="single"
            type="radio"
            data-bean="Single"
            value="Single"
            name="beanType"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Single Origin</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Distinct, high quality coffee from a specific family-owned 
            farm.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="decaf">
          <input
            id="decaf"
            type="radio"
            data-bean="Decaf"
            value="Decaf"
            name="beanType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Decaf</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Just like regular coffee, except the caffeine has been 
            removed.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="blended">
          <input
            id="blended"
            type="radio"
            data-preference="Blended"
            value="Blended"
            name="beanType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Blended</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Combination of two or three dark roasted beans of organic
            coffees.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="quantity" class="subscription__container--quantity 
     box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">How much would you like? 
      </h3>
      <img
        class="question__container--img"
        src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
        alt="arrow"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="250g">
          <input
            id="250g"
            type="radio"
            data-quantity="250g"
            value="250g"
            name="quantity"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">250g</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Perfect for the solo drinker. Yields about 12 delicious 
            cups.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="500g">
          <input
            id="500g"
            type="radio"
            data-quantity="500g"
            value="500g"
            name="quantity"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">500g</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Perfect option for a couple. Yields about 40 delectable 
            cups.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="1000g">
          <input
            id="1000g"
            type="radio"
            data-quantity="1000g"
            value="1000g"
            name="quantity"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">1000g</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Perfect for offices and events. Yields about 90 delightful 
            cups.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="grind" class="subscription__container--grind box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">Want us to grind them? 
      </h3>
      <img
        class="question__container--img"
        src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
        alt="arrow"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="wholebean">
          <input
            id="wholebean"
            type="radio"
            data-grind="Whole Bean"
            value="Whole Bean"
            name="grindType"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Whole Bean</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Best choice if you cherish the full sensory experience.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="filtergrind">
          <input
            id="filtergrind"
            type="radio"
            data-grind="Filter"
            value="Filter"
            name="grindType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            For drip or pour-over coffee methods such as V60 or 
            Aeropress.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="cafetiére">
          <input
            id="cafetiére"
            type="radio"
            data-grind="Cafetiére"
            value="Cafetiére"
            name="grindType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Cafetiére</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Course ground beans specially suited for french press 
            coffee.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="deliver" class="subscription__container--deliver box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">
        How often should we deliver?
      </h3>
      <img
        class="question__container--img"
        src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg"
        alt="arrow"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="everyweek">
          <input
            id="everyweek"
            type="radio"
            data-delivery="Every Week"
            data-price="$7.20"
            value="Every Week"
            name="deliveryType"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Every week</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            $7.20 per shipment. Includes free first-class shipping.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="every2weeks">
          <input
            id="every2weeks"
            type="radio"
            data-delivery="Every 2 weeks"
            data-price="$9.60"
            value="Every 2 weeks"
            name="deliveryType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Every 2 weeks</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            $9.60 per shipment. Includes free priority shipping.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="everymonth">
          <input
            id="everymonth"
            type="radio"
            data-delivery="Every Month"
            data-price="$12.00"
            value="Every Month"
            name="deliveryType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Every Month</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            $12.00 per shipment. Includes free priority shipping.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>



[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: this seems really convoluted.  The problem is caused by the way you are adding your event listeners.  Simply place the listeners on each div

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code, take a look. Rather than try and navigate `parentNode` you can just use `closest()` to find the parent, then `querySelector` to find the input. Also, this sets the default checked items onload, clears out any currently active item on click, and makes sure the radio button gets checked even if you click outside it, but in the target div.

```js
let headers = document.getElementsByClassName("options__container--option");
const container_class = '.options__container--option';

function doClick(e) {
  // clear out all existing active's
  e.preventDefault;
  const actives = e.target.closest('section').querySelectorAll(container_class);
  for (x = 0; x < actives.length; x++) {
    actives[x].classList.remove('active');
  }
  e.target.closest(container_class).classList.add('active');
  // make sure the input is checked
  e.target.closest(container_class).querySelector('input').checked = true
}

window.onload = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i].addEventListener("click", doClick);
  }
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].closest(container_class).classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.options__container--option.active {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<main class="subscription__container">
  <section id="preferences" class="subscription__container--preferences box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">
        How do you drink your coffee?
      </h3>
      <img class="question__container--img" src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="capsule">
          <input
            id="capsule"
            type="radio"
            data-preference="Capsule"
            value="Capsule"
            name="preferences"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Capsule</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Compatible with Nespresso systems and similar brewers.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="filter">
          <input
            id="filter"
            type="radio"
            data-preference="Filter"
            value="Filter"
            name="preferences"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and 
            V60.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="espresso">
          <input
            id="espresso"
            type="radio"
            data-preference="Espresso"
            value="Espresso"
            name="preferences"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Espresso</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavorful
            experience.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="bean" class="subscription__container--beans box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">What type of coffee?</h3>
      <img class="question__container--img" src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="single">
          <input
            id="single"
            type="radio"
            data-bean="Single"
            value="Single"
            name="beanType"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Single Origin</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Distinct, high quality coffee from a specific family-owned 
            farm.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="decaf">
          <input
            id="decaf"
            type="radio"
            data-bean="Decaf"
            value="Decaf"
            name="beanType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Decaf</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Just like regular coffee, except the caffeine has been 
            removed.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="blended">
          <input
            id="blended"
            type="radio"
            data-preference="Blended"
            value="Blended"
            name="beanType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Blended</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Combination of two or three dark roasted beans of organic
            coffees.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="quantity" class="subscription__container--quantity 
     box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">How much would you like?
      </h3>
      <img class="question__container--img" src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="250g">
          <input
            id="250g"
            type="radio"
            data-quantity="250g"
            value="250g"
            name="quantity"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">250g</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Perfect for the solo drinker. Yields about 12 delicious 
            cups.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="500g">
          <input
            id="500g"
            type="radio"
            data-quantity="500g"
            value="500g"
            name="quantity"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">500g</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Perfect option for a couple. Yields about 40 delectable 
            cups.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="1000g">
          <input
            id="1000g"
            type="radio"
            data-quantity="1000g"
            value="1000g"
            name="quantity"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">1000g</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Perfect for offices and events. Yields about 90 delightful 
            cups.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="grind" class="subscription__container--grind box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">Want us to grind them?
      </h3>
      <img class="question__container--img" src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="wholebean">
          <input
            id="wholebean"
            type="radio"
            data-grind="Whole Bean"
            value="Whole Bean"
            name="grindType"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Whole Bean</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Best choice if you cherish the full sensory experience.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="filtergrind">
          <input
            id="filtergrind"
            type="radio"
            data-grind="Filter"
            value="Filter"
            name="grindType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            For drip or pour-over coffee methods such as V60 or 
            Aeropress.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="cafetiére">
          <input
            id="cafetiére"
            type="radio"
            data-grind="Cafetiére"
            value="Cafetiére"
            name="grindType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Cafetiére</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            Course ground beans specially suited for french press 
            coffee.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="deliver" class="subscription__container--deliver box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">
        How often should we deliver?
      </h3>
      <img class="question__container--img" src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="everyweek">
          <input
            id="everyweek"
            type="radio"
            data-delivery="Every Week"
            data-price="$7.20"
            value="Every Week"
            name="deliveryType"
            checked
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Every week</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            $7.20 per shipment. Includes free first-class shipping.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="every2weeks">
          <input
            id="every2weeks"
            type="radio"
            data-delivery="Every 2 weeks"
            data-price="$9.60"
            value="Every 2 weeks"
            name="deliveryType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Every 2 weeks</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            $9.60 per shipment. Includes free priority shipping.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <label class="test__trail" for="everymonth">
          <input
            id="everymonth"
            type="radio"
            data-delivery="Every Month"
            data-price="$12.00"
            value="Every Month"
            name="deliveryType"
          />
          <h4 class="options__container--title">Every Month</h4>
          <p class="options__container--description">
            $12.00 per shipment. Includes free priority shipping.
          </p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the user clicks on the second div.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE - I missed that, thx. Updated

Comment: @Kinglish thank you for your time. This does solve the issue with the div being able to change color if clicked in middle. Yet I have 4 other categories with radio buttons, all have 3 options to choose from. If i go to the category 2, category 1s radio button gets unselected. thank you for assisting once again

Comment: @Felipe - can you update your question with the actual code you're speaking of

Comment: @Kinglish the point is i got 5 categories of radio buttons, i need to be able to select the div from anywhere, currently its only changing its background color if a user clicks on the outer edge, with your code, it worked, i can click anywhere and the div changes background color. yet when i move to the next category, the previous categories radio button gets unselected

Comment: Radio buttons getting unselected is how it works if they all have the same `name` value. Or do you mean they have different names, but the previous 'active' radio loses it's background color?

Comment: @Kinglish thanks for the assistance im going to let this bug stay alive for now, i tried being clear in my question. thank you for helping!

Comment: @Felipe - I had to restructure your code a bit, but it should make things easier. Take a look at my revised answer.

Comment: @Kinglish just seeing this now!